How to select multiple folders with FLTK using Fl_Native_File_Chooser
the following C++ code works fine, except that I do not know how to select multiple folders: each time I click on a folder the previous one is unselected...
When using the option Fl_Native_File_Chooser::BROWSE_MULTI_FILE for files, I am able to select various files
Fl_Native_File_Chooser fnfc;
fnfc.title("Select folders");
fnfc.type(Fl_Native_File_Chooser::BROWSE_MULTI_DIRECTORY);

fnfc.directory(DefaultFolder);           // default directory to use
vector<string> VS;
// Show native chooser
switch (fnfc.show()) {
case -1: Console << format("ERROR: {}\n", fnfc.errmsg()) << endl;    break;  // ERROR
case  1: Console << format(("CANCEL\n"));                      break;  // CANCEL
default:
    for (int i = 0; i < fnfc.count(); i++)
        VS.push_back(fnfc.filename(i));
}
return VS;

I would expect to select multiple folders, as it works for files

You're missing essential information. Since `Fl_Native_File_Chooser' is the (one!) native file chooser of each OS the OS is the most important information. That said, not all "native" file choosers are able to deliver all necessary informations to FLTK, for instance on Linux there are some system dialog based file choosers that are restricted in the values they return to the caller (FLTK). Please see documentation and post info about your platform and which native file chooser the system selects.

Thanks, I am on windows, and using FLTK for about 10 years. I found easier to use when FLTK could be installed through VCPKG

I can't help here with the Windows File Picker (as it is called in MS docs). It looks like the function we're using in FLTK does not support multiple folder selections, whereas multiple file selections are possible. There may be another Windows File/Folder Picker that supports it but from what I read I got the impression that more modern file pickers are only supported on newer Windows versions than FLTK tries to support (e.g. Windows 2000).

That said, I suggest to open either an issue on GitHub (https://github.com/fltk/fltk/issues) or start a discussion in the development section of FLTK's GitHub Discussions (https://github.com/fltk/fltk/discussions/new?category=development). The latter would be preferred so we can discuss whether a compatible improvement is possible. When done we can come back here and post an answer.
